# Magento 2.3.2 Production mode not working

Tags: magento2.3.2, production-mode

i have run production command but not working

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
```

[image]

when I run deploy command

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

and Below type Error showing

> Command returned non-zero exit code: `/opt/alt/php71/usr/bin/php -f

When i run Below deploy command and working Fine but i can not set to production mode

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

[image]

Comment: I was facing similar issue today I had resolved it let me post answer for you

Comment: @HassanAliShahzad Thanks for replay please update your answer here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run below command in sequence for move website to **production** mode.

```
sudo chmod -R 0777 pub var generated
sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
sudo php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production -s
sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile
sudo chmod -R 0777 pub var generated
sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
sudo chmod -R 0777 pub var generated
sudo php bin/magento cache:flush
sudo chmod -R 0777 pub var generated
```

> **Note :** Remove `sudo` if you have not access for root user

Comment: Thanks for replay ok let me try this it and update you

Comment: should be bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f.

Answer (score 2):

First run the following command:

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production -s
```

After that you can run following in sequence:

```
sudo rm -rf  var/cache/* var/page_cache/* generated/*
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/static/ app/etc/ pub/media/
sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/static/ app/etc/ pub/media/
php  -d memory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/static/ app/etc/ pub/media/
php -d memory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:di:compile
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/static/ app/etc/ pub/media/
```

Let me know if still have same issue?

Comment: your command working but compilation command not working 14 % complete after stop it and process finished it https://prnt.sc/payubz

Comment: you are not using my command copy my compilation command exactly

Comment: Also run in same sequence exactly copy & paste

Comment: i have same command as per your suggestion but not woking also production mode not set

Comment: can you show me print screen again please?

Comment: I had change the order can you follow now please?

Comment: would you like to accept the answer please as your production mod set now.

Comment: compilation is not working still +1 for help me set to production mode

Comment: Regarding di:compile please try this `php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento s:d:c`

Comment: @RakeshDonga can you share the di compile screenshot?

Comment: @AshishViradiya di compilation working now but production mode i can not setting up

Comment: Okay share the error.

Comment: Command returned non-zero exit code: `/opt/alt/php71/usr/bin/php -f

Comment: @RakeshDonga For production mode use again above command php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production -s
BTW non zero exit code error means you have some error in you application.
just run : php bin/magento it will show you this issue.
if don't show error then look you application logs server logs etc you will found some fatal in your logs

Comment: @HassanAliShahzad not any error i have checked but when i run production command still this type error showing `Command returned non-zero exit code: `/opt/alt/php71/usr/bin/php -f`

Answer (score 0):

Remove theme folders from pub/static after setting to production mode

```
rm -rf pub/static/frontend/
```

and then run

```
php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

OR

```
php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```